# Home networking routing help and advice

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have this network setup at home. I encounter occasional occurrences where the wired network becomes "no network" on my desktop, which disconnects me from the network.

I come out with this attached picture to illustrate my setup at home. The RJ45 ethernet cables to Router B and my desktop are all run under the floor.

Router A's WiFi is turned off, so Router A is purely for wired internet connection, while Router B is purely for wireless access.

Both Routers are in the wireless Router mode in the configuration.

I am quite frustrated by occasional drop-offs from the network, can I get suggestions on how I can improve the setup?

[image: Click for image illustration]

Comment: Why don’t you just use a switch then say a mesh network kit to handle the WiFi?

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, I happen to have some old routers on hand, so making use of what I have. Any specific recommendation or article I can refer to so improve the setup?

Comment: You can use most routers as a plain old AP, which simplifies things. It's probably worth considering the possibility one of the routers is overloaded, overheating or otherwise malfunctioning... the n56u is old. Would swapping between the routers be an option?

Comment: Hook B to A (LAN to LAN and turn DHCP OFF on B to have one subnet). Then hook your devices to A and / or B as you wish.

Comment: Are you using Router B's WAN port or (one of) the LAN port(s) to connect to Router A? Please add the IP configuration to your diagram as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set router B to AP mode instead of router mode. There really is no reason to use two routers unless your devices are / must be in different subnets.

Alternatively, you can try to deactivate the DHCP function on router B. Depending on the router settings you might have to use the LAN port instead of the WAN port on router B.

If, for some reason, you need two routers (in router mode), make sure you are using the WAN ports to connect the routers to the rest of the network.

Note: From your diagram, it looks a bit like your ISP's device is acting as a router ("used as kind of switch"), if this is the case you should deactivate the routing and DHCP functions on both routers (also see my comment and please give more specific info about the devices)